# What kind of time series problem this is and how to solve it?

Tags: time-series, python, prediction

Let's say that my dataset looks like this:

timestamp (daily), serial_number, device_type, stat1, stat2... statn, failure.

One device type can contain many serial numbers. For each serial number stat1-statn have some metrics. Failure column is 0 - no failure or 1 - failed.

I have to predict which serial number will fail in the nearby (next 7 days) future.

I believe that this is a multivariate time series problem.
Can I use SARIMAX (statsmodels) for such time series?

Comment: Unfortunately SARIMAX is not relevant here. VAR models are more relevant or just going with a full "deep learning" CNN and/or LSTM model.

Comment: As SARIMAX has signature like this:

SARIMAX(endog, exog=None, order=(1, 0, 0), seasonal_order=(0, 0, 0, 0), trend=None, measurement_error=False, time_varying_regression=False, mle_regression=True, simple_differencing=False, enforce_stationarity=True, enforce_invertibility=True, hamilton_representation=False, concentrate_scale=False, **kwargs)

I hoped that I will be able to use failure column as endog, and all feature columns for exog. So you are suggesting VAR(MA) for this purpose or CNN/LSTM. Thanks.

Comment: VAR first, gives you reasonably competitive base-line with a well-understood theoretical framework behind. CNN/LSTM afterwards to see if they are indeed improvements and not just riding the DL-hype train.